# C++11 strange brace initialization behavior

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't understand how C++11 brace initialization rules work here.
Having this code:

```
struct Position_pod {
    int x,y,z;
};

class Position {
public:
    Position(int x=0, int y=0, int z=0):x(x),y(y),z(z){}
    int x,y,z;
};

struct text_descriptor {
    int             id;
    Position_pod    pos;
    const int       &constNum;
};

struct text_descriptor td[3] = {
     {0, {465,223}, 123},
     {1, {465,262}, 123},
};

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that the array is declared to have 3 elements, but only 2 initializers are provided.

However it compiles without error, which sounds strange, as the last array element's reference member will be uninitialized. Indeed, it has NULL value:

```
(gdb) p td[2].constNum 
$2 = (const int &) @0x0: <error reading variable>
```

And now the "magic": I changed Position_pod to Position

```
struct text_descriptor {
    int             id;
    Position_pod    pos;
    const int       &constNum;
};
```

becomes this:

```
struct text_descriptor {
    int             id;
    Position        pos;
    const int       &constNum;
};
```

and now it gives the expected error:

```
error: uninitialized const member ‘text_descriptor::constNum'
```

My question: Why it compiles in the first case, when it should give an error (as in the second case).
The difference is, that Position_pod uses C - style brace initialization and Position uses C++11 - style initialization, which call Position's constructor. But how does this affect the possibility to leave a reference member uninitialized?

(Update)
Compiler: 
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Comment: Compiler version is important. [Clang 3.5 and GCC 4.9.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4669040f8cc1bd3e) don't compile this.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. I can reproduce on GCC 4.8 and earlier, so looks like it's been fixed in 4.9.

Comment: MSVC 2013 doesn't compile this as well.

Comment: The problem is not that you have "too few" initializers, it's that `const` refs must be initialized when instantiated.

Comment: @remyabel GCC 4.9.2 does compile it with `-std=c++03`, though.

Comment: I guess, there should be a default constructor in Position class.

Comment: @PavelOganesyan: There is a default constructor in that class.

Comment: @MikeSeymour My bad. Yes, there is.

Comment: Please, call a language lawyer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It will be clear that

> ```
> struct text_descriptor td[3] = {
>      {0, {465,223}, 123},
>      {1, {465,262}, 123},
> };
> ```

is list-initialisation, and that the initialiser list is not empty.

C++11 says ([dcl.init.list]p3):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - If the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.
> - Otherwise, if `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
> - ...

[dcl.init.aggr]p1:

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

`td` is an array, so it is an aggregate, so aggregate initialisation is performed.

[dcl.init.aggr]p7:

> If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list (8.5.4).

This is the case here, so `td[2]` is initialised from an empty initialiser list, which ([dcl.init.list]p3 again) means it is value-initialised.

Value-initialisation, in turn, means ([dcl.init]p7):

> To value-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), ...
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if `T`'s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
>     called.
> - ...

Your class `text_descriptor` is a class with no user-provided constructor, so `td[2]` is first zero-initialised, and then its constructor is called.

Zero-initialisation means ([dcl.init]p5):

> To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if `T` is a scalar type (3.9), ...
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, ...
> - if `T` is an array type, ...
> - if `T` is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

This is well-defined regardless of `text_descriptor`'s default constructor: it just zero-initialises the non-reference members and sub-members.

Then the default constructor is called, if it is non-trivial. Here's how the default constructor is defined ([special]p5):

> A *default constructor* for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
>   as defaulted (8.4). An implicitly-declared default constructor is an inline public member of its class. A defaulted default constructor for class `X` is defined as deleted if:
>
> - ...
> - any non-static data member with no brace-or-equal-initializer is of reference type,
> - ...
>
> A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - no non-static data member of its class has a brace-or-equal-initializer, and
> - all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default constructors, and
> - for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default constructor.
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is non-trivial.

So, the implicitly defined constructor is deleted, as expected, *but* it is also trivial, if `pos` is a POD type (!). Because the constructor is trivial, it is not called. Because the constructor is not called, the fact that it is deleted is not a problem.

This is a gaping hole in C++11, which has since been fixed. It happened to have been fixed to deal with [inaccessible trivial default constructors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1507), but the fixed wording also covers deleted trivial default constructors. N4140 (roughly C++14) says in [dcl.init.aggr]p7 (emphasis mine):

> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized **and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked**, and if
>     `T` has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

As T.C. pointed out in the comments, [another DR](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301) also changed so that `td[2]` is still initialised from an empty initialiser list, but that empty initialiser list now implies aggregate initialisation. That, in turn, implies each of `td[2]`'s members is initialised from an empty initialiser list as well ([dcl.init.aggr]p7 again), so would seem to initialise the reference member from `{}`.

[dcl.init.aggr]p9 then says (as remyabel had pointed out in a now-deleted answer):

> If an incomplete or empty *initializer-list* leaves a member of reference type uninitialized, the program is ill-formed.

It is unclear to me that this applies to references initialised from the implicit `{}`, but compilers do interpret it as such, and there's not much else that could be meant by it.

Comment: References can't be value-initialized.

Comment: @remyabel I know, but value-initialisation of a class doesn't imply value-initialisation of that class's members.

Comment: @bogdan It does have a default constructor. That default constructor is deleted, so it is an error if that default constructor is used, but because of a gap in the wording, it doesn't even get used. I quoted [special]p5 from the standard, which specifies when a default constructor is defined, and how it gets defined.

Comment: C++14 also swapped the first two bullets of [dcl.init.list]p2, so that it's always aggregate initialization whether or not the initializer list is empty.

Comment: @T.C. I addressed that in an edit, but it's not clear to me whether the program would be valid in C++14. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: @hvd I can't think of anything else [dcl.init.aggr]p9 could be referring to. Also, the changes made here are all DRs, so they should be implemented by compilers in C++11 mode as well.

Comment: @T.C. Oh yeah, agreed, that's a good way of telling what might be meant. :) Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The first version (the one with _pod suffix) still works but gives no error because for the z value, the default value of int is chosen (the 0). Idem for the const int reference.

In the second version, you cannot define a const reference without giving it a value. The compiler gives you an error because later you cannot assign any value to it.

In addition, the compiler you're using plays an important role here, maybe it's a bug, just because you are declaring a class member before an int member.

Comment: But both versions (try to) initialise a reference without giving it a value. The question is about the number of initialisers for the array, not for the `Position` member of each array element. (And to answer your question: to demonstrate how the compiler's behaviour changes if you change the type of that member from POD to non-POD.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour it's a compiler problem. And you are including also a class in a structure. It would be better if you keep the structures easy, or perhaps use the constructor in the first structure

Comment: "it's a compiler problem" - so it would seem. But your answer doesn't say that, and seems to say that the first version is well-formed, even though it isn't.

Comment: maybe it's an ordering bug..because you define a class member before the int